# NSTimer not functioning as expected

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstimer

I have looked a number of different posts related to NSTimer issues, and I have tried so many different combinations to get it to work the way I want, however I am still unable to get it working correctly.

I have two requirements for timers, one is a repeating timer that pulls data from a web service every 10 seconds. This seems to be working fine. The second requirement is that whenever a value is updated in the interface, that a non-repeating timer is created that will change the text colour of the value in the interface 0.3 seconds after the value changes.

I can only seem to get the text colour changing the first time, and it will not change subsequently... It is driving me insane.

Here's some code...

In the interface I define a property:

```
@property (strong) NSTimer *colorTimer;
```

In the implementation, this is the function that gets called whenever the value needs to be updated in the interface:

```
- (void)setBtcValue:(float)value
{
    bool moveIsPositive = (value > btcValue) ? true : false;
    bool moveIsNeutral = (value == btcValue) ? true : false;
    btcValue = value;
    if(moveIsPositive && !moveIsNeutral)
    {
        [uiValueTextField setTextColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
        self.colorTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(resetTextColor) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    } else if(!moveIsPositive && !moveIsNeutral)
    {
        [uiValueTextField setTextColor:[NSColor redColor]];
        self.colorTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.3 target:self selector:@selector(resetTextColor) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [uiValueTextField setStringValue: [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:btcValue]]];
    [uiValueTextField sizeToFit];
    NSRect newFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, uiValueTextField.bounds.size.width+20, self.view.bounds.size.height);

    [self.view setFrame:newFrame];
}
```

The function that is fired when the timer goes off is as follows:

```
- (void) resetTextColor
{
    NSLog(@"Timer Fired");
    [uiValueTextField setTextColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    [self.colorTimer invalidate];
    self.colorTimer = nil;
}
```

I know it doesn't make sense to have the timer repeating and then manually invalidating it, but as stated I have tried this using repeats set to NO, using local variables instead of a property, using weak, strong, assign, retain... The behaviour is ALWAYS the same... Fires the first time, never after that.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated... I am a C# developer learning Objective-C, and as such everything is still very unfamiliar to me! Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Here is the AppDelegate that sets up the main timer which is the caller of setBtcValue:

```
#import "LBAppDelegate.h"
#import "LBBitStampCommunicator.h"

@implementation LBAppDelegate
@synthesize statusItem;
@synthesize statusItemViewController;
@synthesize bitStampManager;
@synthesize dataTimer;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [self activateStatusMenu];
    bitStampManager = [[LBBitStampManager alloc] init];
    bitStampManager.communicator = [[LBBitStampCommunicator alloc] init];
    bitStampManager.communicator.delegate = bitStampManager;
    bitStampManager.delegate = self;

    dataTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(fetchData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)activateStatusMenu {
    NSStatusBar *bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
    statusItem = [bar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    statusItemViewController = [[LBStatusItemViewController alloc]init];
    [statusItem setView:statusItemViewController.view];
    [statusItemViewController setBtcValue: 8888.88f];
}

- (void)didReceiveData:(LBTicker *)data {
    [statusItemViewController setBtcValue:[data.last floatValue]];
}

- (void)fetchingDataFailedWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [statusItemViewController setBtcValue:0.00f];
}

- (void)fetchData {
    [bitStampManager.communicator getData];
}

@end
```

Comment: Whats the frequency of `setBtcValue:` being called? sharing the sample code would be heplful.

Comment: Essentially it is called once every 10 seconds. I've added the AppDelegate code above to further clarify.

Comment: Have you confirmed with logs that either the "if" or "else" clause of the setBtcValue method is executed every 10 seconds?

Comment: BTW, it would be simpler to eliminate the 0.3 second timer entirely, and just use [uiValueTextField performSelector:@selector(setTextColor:) withObject:[UIColor blackColor] afterDelay:0.3];

Comment: I have confirmed that the code is running the clauses consistently... Interestingly however your solution with the afterDelay parameter seems far more elegant. I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered instead of trying to spawn a timer; to do an animation with a 0.3 sec fade in? That way you just listen for the notification and set off the animation and let the system do the rest.

Comment: This is something I was planning to do later on as I expected it to be more complex to achieve. I have just tried extending NSTextField to animate the text colour change however it just fades the text out, then back in with the different colour. Do you know of any examples of this type of thing that might help?